# PdfBox - version - files issue

Tags: java, apache, pdfbox

When i have used the following dependency, `1.8.6` or `1.8.7`, i am not able to get the class `PDFieldTreeNode`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have checked the jar i have downloaded, and also the sources jar as well, but the file is not present.

But when i changed to `<version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>`, i am able to get the file.

What is the issue in other versions, also this is not the new file added.

Comment: How do you say that this is not the new file added..? How do you know?

Comment: @ashokramcse check there svn repository, from last few releases there are modifications done in this file along with other files as well, but not added as a new.

Comment: Check the JavaDocs of pdfbox http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.6/javadocs/ there is no class as such that.

Comment: @ashokramcse i actually reffered [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/commits@pdfbox.apache.org/msg02551.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the PDFBOX JavaDocs there is no class as `PDFieldTreeNode`

http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.6/javadocs/

http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.5/javadocs/

As on your comment `check there svn repository, from last few releases there are modifications done in this file along with other files as well, but not added as a new.`

The release date of the version `1.8.6` is `(Jun 22, 2014)` refer [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin%3Achangelog-panel)

The first commit was made on the class file `PDFieldTreeNode` `(Aug 16, 2014)` I referred it on the SVN log.

[image: First Commit]

Answer (score 1):

I have verified it.

Issue with id - `PDFBOX-2261` has not been added until `1.8.7 release`.

Was added in `<version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>`

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/form/

http://www.apache.org/dist/pdfbox/1.8.7/RELEASE-NOTES.txt